# What are the recommended file system permissions for a WordPress installation on IIS7.5?

Tags: security, wordpress, iis, permissions, content-management-system

I'm looking for a good, general set of permissions that would allow for uploads by the IIS_IUSRS account, automatic updates, etc., without simply granting modify/write access to IIS_IUSRS for the entire site.

Comment: checkout this site.. what version of IIS are you using also ..? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa954062(BTS.20).aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The least permission needed is for the IIS account to have read and write permissions on the `/wp-content/uploads/` folder and read permissions on the rest. This will however not allow the user to install plugins, use the theme editor or install any WordPress updates.

In order to allow plugin installs you need to give the IIS account write permission to the `/wp-content/plugins/` folder. To allow the use of theme editor you need to the IIS account write permissions on the `/wp-content/themes/` folder.

In order to allow for the user to install WordPress updates you need to give read/write permission on the root folder where you installed WordPress. This is the least secure option but on the other hand the most common way to install it.

Comment: I suppose a good compromise would be to add read/write permission on the /wp-content/ as a whole?

Comment: Also, if set to read-only, is there still another way to allow an authenticated administrator to do install/update?

Comment: If you have a copy of the site on a development/staging environment you can do the update there and FTP it over to the live site. Another option might be (not tested or even deployed) to also allow Windows authentication on the site (next to anonymous) and create a (hidden) page that triggers IIS to ask the user for authentication. This will allow an admin to login with a Windows account that has enough permissions for WordPress to do the upgrade.